# AngularJS: Add attribute, compile directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to somehow add directive as simple attribute in `compile` function and let angular handle compiling of added directive?

Provided example bellow obviously does not work, but my proper question would be, what is the cleanest way to achieve that?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('testOne', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 10000,
    compile: function (element, attrs) {
      
      element.attr('test-two', '');
    }
  };
});

app.directive('testTwo', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 10,
    compile: function (element, attrs) {
      console.log(2);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">


  <div test-one></div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the link phase, you can call `$compile(element)(scope)` to recompile the element to allow AngularJS to pick up the newly added directive. However, to prevent an infinite loop (since your initial directive will also be re-compiled), you should remove the initial directive's attribute first:

```
link: function (scope, element) {
    element.removeAttr('test-one');
    element.attr('test-two', '');

    $compile(element)(scope);
}
```

**Edit**: You may also want to set `terminal: true` on your initial directive to prevent other directives from kicking in before your attribute massaging is done. You may also have to play around with the priority of the directive for similar reasons.

Comment: Ok so this is the cleanest way :) I wanted to know if I can somehow avoid multiple compilations. Thanks!

Comment: Another question if you know answer perhaps. How can I programatically change attribute of an element so that $observe in another directive will trigger? I tried attrs.$set and no luck.

Comment: If the directive is not actively watching for changes to the attribute expression, you're out of luck. I'd peek into to source code of the other directive (if it's not your directive) and see if there's any watching going on.

Comment: Yes, except another $compile :) don't like this though..:) Thanks

Comment: +1  @AtesGoral "to prevent an infinite loop (since your initial directive will also be re-compiled), you should remove the initial directive's attribute first" - Thank You